# How can I call methods within controller (RoR)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am very new to RoR and I have played around the source code. But I have a problem that I already built a 'def A' for creating first CSV file, and 'def B' for creating second CSV file. Each 'def' has its own button, but I have the third button to create all CSVs (to produce output from first and second CSV files.)

What is the possible way to do it?

```
def first_csv
...
end

def second_csv
..
end

def all_csv
<< how to call get first and second csv >>
end
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as you imagine:

```
def all_csv
  first_csv
  second_csv
end
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick help. :) I had tried that before but I still got error like  'ActionController::DoubleRenderError (Can only render or redirect once per action):'

Comment: Do you have the two methods within your controller? You should move them into the model and just call them in your controller..double render error means, that you try to render or redirect in one controller action twice. You should wrap that into an if-else-clause if necessary..

Comment: I found my problem that I try render twice because both methods called 'def stream_csv' that contains render :text => Proc.new { |response, output| csv = FasterCSV.new(output, :row_sep => "\r\n") yield csv}

Answer (score 2):

Muntasim's answer is correct, but I have to add some additional information.

Ruby provides two types of methods..class methods and instance methods.

```
class MyClass < AvtiveRecord::Base

  # class method
  def self.foo
    # do something
    # within this scope the keyword "self" belongs to the class
  end

  # another class method which calls internally the first one
  def self.bar
    something = foo # self.foo could also be written
    # do something with something
    # within this scope the keyword "self" belongs to the class
  end

  # instance method
  def foo
    # do something
    # if you use the keyword "self" within an instance method, it belongs to the instance
  end

  # another instance method which calls class and the first instance method
  def bar
    mystuff = Myclass.bar # if you want to call the class method you cannot use "self", you must directly call the class
    mystuff2 = foo # self.foo is the same, because of the instance scope
    return [mystuff, mystuff2]
  end

end
```

You can call the last instance method like following

```
instance = MyClass.first
instance.bar
```

Comment: Thanks, that's make me understand the syntax better :)